# Windows auth with fallback to login form

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, iis, windows-authentication

I have a ASP.NET MVC web site in iis with Windows authentication enabled. The website is only in intranet today.

Now I would like to let internet users access the same website but let them sign in through a form with username and password. So when windows auth fails (or when the user uses a specific host name?) I want to show the login form.

Is it possible? How?

Comment: Will the internet users have Windows (ActiveDirectory) credentials?  I know that if they do, you can accept logins domain\user from an outside users.  But if this isn't the case then you are going to have some sort of mixed authentication mode?

Comment: Doing this mixed authentication in a single site is very difficult. If you just go with the form, the whole thing will be a lot simpler. Although, you could host two different instances of the site with each having separate auth, but that poses its own challenges.

Comment: You can use both internal accounts as part of the application as well as "external" authentication services. ADFS would be a great match for what you're after since a user would still be prompted to log in, they would just use their windows credentials. ADFS would handle the authentication

Comment: The internet users will probably not have domain accounts. How could I use ADFS? Any examples?

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible. Microsoft used to have ISA Server for that https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sooraj-sec/2009/12/20/password-change-using-form-based-authentication-in-isa-server-2006/ Now due to the product retirement, you need to switch to a third party alternative or develop you own.